# Set column value to foreign key based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and have imported data from an Excel file into my tables.

My tables consist of:

- BH_Overview (foreign key table) [BH_OverView Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMzxt.png)
- BH_Equipment (primary key table) [BH_Equipment Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gJMs.png)

I have different types of equipment and looking to split it out into its own table called `BH_Equipment` and link it into the main table `BH_Overview`.

I have my tables created and constraints made, however when data is imported into table I have just stored the equipment name in the the `BH_Overview` table in a column "Equipment" that isn't link with `BH_Equipment`.

I'm wondering how I go about updating the `equipmentId` column based on what is in the equipment column in the `BH_Overview` table to match the `Id` in the `BH_Equipment` table.

You can see I have the foreign keys done for Factory Area and responsibility and that was done manually with update statement as only a few foreign keys to link but with equipment there is 291 types in the `BH_Equipment` table.

I have tried a update and inner joins, but can't get my head around it. Apologies if I have went about this an awful way, relatively new to SQL so please show if there is a much easier way or if this has been asked before please link and ill give it a look.

UPDATE:
[@Charlieface - error message appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pGfR.png)

Comment: Both the below solution should face the same error message, `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` but you correct it without mentioning in your question or even comments. You should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is good, but for SQL Server you can update much more easily directly through a join:

```sql
update o
set equipmentId = e.id
from BH_OverView o
join BH_Equipment e on e.equipment = o.Equipment;
```

This rough syntax also works on Postgres, MySQL/MariaDB and the later versions of SQLite.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tried running this statement but the following message appears: see image attached to updated question at the top

Comment: It may work or not, based on the database version,

Comment: This statement worked for me. Although i had to add an ON statement after the join.

Comment: Sorry about that `where` should have been `on`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have the content of the column `Equipment` in the table `BH_OverView` match one of column `equipment` content in the table `BH_Equipment`

Then by the following SQL statement, you populate the corresponding `equipmentId` in the table `BH_OverView`

```
update BH_OverView
set equipmentId = (select id from BH_Equipment 
where BH_Equipment.equipment=BH_OverView.Equipment)
```

after verifying the content of `equipmentId` in the table `BH_OverView`, you may drop the column `Equipment` from the table `BH_OverView` by

```
alter table BH_OverView drop column Equipment
```

I am using standard SQL which should operate on the majority of Databases.

***Based on your comment***

you got an error message

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

This means that in your table `BH_Equipment`, you have one more `equipment` that has the same name. You have repeated equipment name in rows of the table `BH_Equipment`

```
to get this equipment and the number of time they exist, use the following SQL statement
```

select equipment, count(id)
from BH_Equipment
group by equipment
having count(id)>1

```
delete one of the repeated rows, then the error message will not exist.
```

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres you can update through a join

Comment: Hi @nour-allah hussein i have tried this statement but it is bringing back the error message as shown below: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I have add my comments in the answer.